# Alternate translations of "why are you asking me this question"

Tags: translation, grammar

几个”Why are you asking me this question?"的翻译是什么？

What are some possible ways to translate "Why are you asking me this question?".

最明显的是（1）。

The most obvious is (1):

```
1) 你为什么问我这个问题？
```

可是我想到几个为这个意思用连动结构的可疑的办法。哪些没有语病？有一个没语病的用连动结构的句子吗？

However, there are some ways I can think of several dubious ways to use a serial verb construction to express this idea. Are any of them grammatical? Is there a sentence using the serial verb construction that does work?

```
A) 你为什么 把这个问题 问我。
B) 你为什么 问我 问这个问题。
C) 你为什么 给我 问这个问题。
D) 你为什么 对我 问这个问题。
```

An example topicalizing `你`.

```
E) 你这个问题为什么问我。
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to translate "Why are you asking me this question?".
Your first sentence is a correct way of expression.
In China we never use any of options A, B, C, D, or E.
The following are several otehr ways to express this in Chinese, but we rarely use it in daily expression in China:

- 你为何问我这个问题？
- 你问我这个问题的原因是什么？
- 你问我这个问题的理由是什么？

Comment: Is there any verb you can use to mark "我” as the recipient of the question? Like "给" in "我送一本书给他"?

Answer (score 1):

1. is good. A to D are not good. E is good.

Other ways to express: "Why are you asking me this question?"

你问我那个问题的原因是什么？

是什么原因让你这样问我？

Comment: How about 这个问题你为什么问我

Comment: 有一个对的两个动词的句子吗？”...说...“呢？